# VBA POWERSHELL EXEC Runtime error : system can not find the specified file

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, vba

i am trying to run a few powershellscript from vba excel , it was working fine .
But now am getting error of system can not find the file .

```
Sub Button1_Click()
strCommand = "Powershell -File ""C:\Users\Sagar.Patro\Documents\Powershell\xyz.ps1"""
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)  *<- debug highlighting this line*
    strOutput = WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll
End Sub
```

Comment: What changed when it stopped working? Did you move the code to a different machine, or were there software updates?

Comment: Is it possible that `C:\Windows\System32` is no longer in your PATH?

Comment: what's the output of `where powershell` ?